# Azure deployment versions

Tags: rest, service, azure, cloud

I will try to make it simplify. I am using windows azure cloud to host our web services and databases. and these web services are accessible via URL: "https://server.mydomain.com"

now we made a few major changes to our model and hence web services as a whole. This breaks the API interface for older users. Now we want to deploy the latest version on URL: "https://server.mydomain.com/v2" so that old users can still access the older version.

I searched around SO and other resources but i couldnt find a definite answer how to deploy new version without messing up the old version.

Anything in right direction will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In one of the projects I was working on, we built in a versioning scheme on top of our Web API.  We used [this tutorial](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/versioning-asp-net-web-api-services-using-http-headers/) to get started.  I would recommend starting there.

Sorry for the generic answer, if you post some more specifics I will make some updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to deploy separate cloud service and use "v2.server.mydomain.com"